# MVC3 - passing NEW-LINE to ModelState.AddModelError

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When an error occurs on the back-end, the MVC controller returns a message via the
`ModelState.AddModelError("", "message");`

I would like to have that 'message' **display in 2 lines**, so I would like to put a **`"\r\n"`**
or a **`"<br />"`** in between.

I'm using Razor to display the Message using `@Html.ValidationSummary();`
But the HTML Output from the View displays that as **`&lt;br/&gt;`**

What is the best way to pass New-Lines on a message and get it interpreted into a real 
 tag at the HTML output level?

================================
**Controller code:**

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Line one <br /> Line two.");
return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (ActionResult) PartialView("ViewName", model) 
            : View(model);
```

**View code:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tv" })) 
{
    @if (Html.ValidationSummary() != null)
        @Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary(true).ToString()))   

    ....
}
```

Comment: Please provide more informations, what you want to do ?

Comment: The ValidationSummary helper automatically HTML encodes the message. You will have to write a custom helper if you want to achieve that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ValidationSummary helper HTML encodes error messages and this is by design. It means that you cannot use HTML tags as they will be encoded. So you could write a custom helper which doesn't encode:

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var formContextForClientValidation = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled ? htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext : null;
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (formContextForClientValidation == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var ulBuilder = new TagBuilder("ul");

        ModelState modelState;
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, out modelState))
        {
            foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
            {
                string userErrorMessageOrDefault = error.ErrorMessage;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userErrorMessageOrDefault))
                {
                    var liBuilder = new TagBuilder("li");
                    liBuilder.InnerHtml = userErrorMessageOrDefault;
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(liBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
                }
            }
        }

        if (stringBuilder.Length == 0)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("<li style=\"display:none\"></li>");
        }
        ulBuilder.InnerHtml = stringBuilder.ToString();

        TagBuilder divBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
        divBuilder.AddCssClass(htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid ? HtmlHelper.ValidationSummaryValidCssClassName : HtmlHelper.ValidationSummaryCssClassName);
        divBuilder.InnerHtml = ulBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        if (formContextForClientValidation != null)
        {
            if (!htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled)
            {
                divBuilder.GenerateId("validationSummary");
                formContextForClientValidation.ValidationSummaryId = divBuilder.Attributes["id"];
                formContextForClientValidation.ReplaceValidationSummary = false;
            }
        }
        return new HtmlString(divBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.MyValidationSummary()
```

It is the following line in our custom helper which explicitly doesn't HTML encode:

```
liBuilder.InnerHtml = userErrorMessageOrDefault;
```

In the original helper it looks like this:

```
liBuilder.SetInnerText(userErrorMessageOrDefault);
```

Comment: If I got a $ for every time one of your answers helped me out Darin, I wouldn't be working right now.

Answer (score 12):

Try wrapping the validation summary in an `Html.Raw` and a `Server.HtmlDecode`, like so:

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary().ToString()))
```

Comment: When I put that line of code, it does not even show the partial view. It gives me a "500 internal server error".

Comment: I revised my answer.  I tested the revised code, and it returned the error message with a line break when I had `<br />` in the error message.

Comment: The problem is with @Html.ValidationSummary; I tried replacing it with ViewBag.Temp ..and it did work. So we need to find out how to make the ValidationSummary work before we start thinking to replace it totally.

Comment: Maybe I have the Validation inside a Ajax.BeginForm. would that be the difference ?

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the view you are trying to return.

Comment: @Filu, there's not much you could do with ValidationSummary. As I said in my comment it HTML encodes messages by default and this is by design. So you need to write a custom helper for this.

Comment: Works for me!

`@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }).ToString()))`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov your custom helper is great thanks - but Coundsellorben and Ray are correct: this solution works too. A good quick option for someone only using it once or twice in a project. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Controller:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("MyError", "Line 1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line 2");
```

Razor:

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">@Html.ValidationSummary()</span>
```

Comment: inserting Environment.NewLine as proposed here, did not work for me.

Comment: @levteck Any thoughts on why it would work for me and not you?

Comment: @MarioLevesque Worked for me. Make sure you stylize the `span` element like in the example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, however this is the top result when I Google, so my solution may help someone.

I went around the problem and added a separate line for each error message line.  Displays beautifully.

Controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(EditModel model)
    {
            try
            {
                //... do update
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
                {
                    var messages = ex.Message.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    foreach (var message in messages)
                    {
                        this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
                }
            }
        //...

        return this.View(model);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you use the first param key in AddModelError to refer to an input